# Resources for Customizing TFS Build 2010

Tags: workflow, build-automation, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I am looking to create a way to build my Legacy Delphi 5 and 6 apps via TFS Build (using TFS 2010).

I was fairly dangerous with the MSBuild way of doing things and I think I can still do that, but I would like to get into the Work Flow way of doing it.

Are there any resources out there that discuss customizing a TFS Build via Windows Work Flow?  Especially how to override the solution concept and how to compile and report errors.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to look into creating a custom workflow activity. There's a pretty good article on how to do that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Workflow-Activity-for-TFS-Build-2010.aspx#tb). That said, I'm creating one now and finding it to be a pretty fiddly a annoying process.